# Calculate sum from two queries?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, join, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to calculate the total cost for the job_id including the wages and cost of fittings.
I only manage to calculate one at time. I need to sum both wages and fittings cost by job_id.

staff_on_job  Table(FK: staff_id,job_id)

[image: Staff_on_job table]

fittings Table

[image: Fittings]

job_fittings  Table(FK: job_id,fitting_name)

[image: job_fittings]

Calculate the wages on per job_id

```
select job_id ,sum(hours*30)from staffs_on_job group by job_id;
```

Output

[image: wages]

calculate the total fitting cost on per job_id

```
select jf.job_id ,sum(f.cost) 
from jobs_fittings jf left OUTER JOIN fittings f
on( jf.FITTING_NAME = f.FITTING_NAME)
group by jf.JOB_ID;
```

Output

[image]

What is the query to calculate total cost of a job_id with both wages and fitting cost? Can the sum from both queries be joined?

Comment: What are you using? Microsoft SQL, MySQL, Oracle, etc?

Comment: oracle sql develpoer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to break down the query into two simple queries and then join them together. This solution assumes that a job will always have someone working it but might not have any fitting costs (hence the left join from wages to fittings). Really this is a deficiency in the schema design as there should be a job table (maybe there is one that you haven't included in your example) which you would left join both wages and fittings to.

```
WITH  job_wage_costs AS
(
   SELECT   job_id,
            SUM(hours) * 30 AS wage_costs
   FROM     staff_on_job
   GROUP BY job_id
),
job_fitting_costs AS (
   SELECT   job_id,
            SUM(COST) AS fitting_costs
   FROM     job_fittings jf
   JOIN     fittings f ON (f.fitting_name = jf.fitting_name)
   GROUP BY job_id
)
SELECT   jw.job_id,
         jw.wage_costs,
         jf.fitting_costs
FROM     job_wage_costs jw
LEFT OUTER JOIN job_fitting_costs jf ON (jf.job_id = jw.job_id);
```

---

```
JOB_ID   WAGE_COSTS  FITTING_COSTS 
1        60          20
2        480         164.99
6        1200        199.99
12       1200        320.98
9        90
```

As an aside, the design of your fittings table could do with changing as it isn't a [normalized design](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). By reproducing the fitting type in every row you make it very difficult to change the wording of those fitting types in the future as you'd need to change every row - they should be in a fitting_type table which can then be joined to fittings.

Comment: there are some other tables too.Fitting_type is foreign key, can you write a single join query for this. i need fittingcost+wages by job_id

Comment: This is a single query, it just uses the WITH statement to break the calculations down into subqueries. To get the total cost just add `NVL(jw.wage_costs,0) + NVL(jf.fitting_costs,0) AS total_cost` to the final SELECT statement.

Comment: Is the table called staffs_on_job or staff_on_job - you refer to it as both in your question, perhaps that's the issue. The query I provided works fine locally with my own copies of the tables in your example.

Comment: Not that comes to mind, the problem is if you don't split out the fittings and wage queries the cardinality (number of rows) of the underlying data is affected, so the SUM() functions return incorrect data. You could simplify it by creating views that contain the WITH clause queries, meaning you only need the final SELECT statement though.

Answer (score 0):

the easiest solution is to join your 2 query:

```
select A.job_id, A.wages,B.fittingcost, total = A.wages + B.fittingcost
from (
       select job_id ,sum(hours*30) wages from staffs_on_job group by job_id
     ) A
     join (
       select jf.job_id ,sum(f.cost) fittingcost
       from jobs_fittings jf left OUTER JOIN fittings f
       on( jf.FITTING_NAME = f.FITTING_NAME)
       group by jf.JOB_ID
     ) B on (A.job_id = B.job_id)
```

be aware that the above will not properly handle the case when one of the 2 tables does not contain the job_id you are looking for; if one of the tables does not contain that job_id then the result will be completely empty.

Comment: says from keyword missing double checked it!